# gitlab : How to bypass ESLint errors while trying to commit

Tags: reactjs, npm, gitlab, githooks

I was trying to commit the changes to my dev branch in Gitlab, but whenever i try to commit changes it shows the errors of ESLint and the commit gets aborted.

I tried cloning the repository from dev branch and made changes and installed dependencies using '**npm install**' and the errors seems to appear only when dependencies are installed.

Tested without installing npm dependencies, made changes to the code and tried to commit , and Voila! it worked, and changes pushed to the dev branch.

***Help me to avoid these errors appearing at the time of pushing the changes.***

(Please check the image below to view the errors displayed)

[image]

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How to fix these errors displayed? Actually i was able to run the code without any issues on my local server, but cannot push the code to gitlab. I need a fix to avoid these kind of errors ,appearing when i try to push it to gitlab. @GabrielBleu

Comment: There is a linter task with `pre-commit` hook in your code and instead of *avoiding* these errors you should probably be working towards fixing them

Answer (score 4):

It worked when i used

```
git commit -m "Commit Message" --no-verify
```

and this is what i was looking for. I was looking to bypass without fixing those ESLint errors!

Comment: Now I'am searching "How to prevent eslint error being pushed to repo". So it validated on git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Fix lint errors before pushing. If you don't understand a rule, search it on eslint doc.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for circumventing linting rules on a commit. Obviously, a PR with failing linting should never be merged, but as commits should be limited to as small a size as possible sometimes it is good to commit parts of code that pass even though not all uncached code passes linting. This answer does not answer the question and is rather condescending.

Comment: Agree if dev branch is a feature branch, breaking a shared branch is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put `--no-verify` before `-m` (message):

```
git commit --no-verify -m 'commit message'
```

Comment: This answer just duplicates the top answer and is 3 years late.  Voting to delete.

Comment: I have tried the top answer but that is not working currently, to add --no-verify before -m its worked for me, thats added this answer

Comment: @VigneshwaranChandrasekaran That wasn't clear because you left all the formatting the same. The subsequent editor was also confused about what was a command and what was text.